# The pop-up 'Figure 1' is blank after using plt.show() to plot a 3D graph of a binary function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using VScode to plot a 3D graph of a binary function. But after running the code, the pop-up figure is blank and doesn't show the plot.
Below is the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

figure = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(figure)
X = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
Y = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = (np.sin(X)*np.sin(Y))/(X*Y)  # f(x,y)=(sin(x)*sin(y))/(x*y)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='rainbow')
plt.show()
```

[After running the code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IjYt.png)

[I have checked the setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpHkR.png)
I also tried to draw a 2D image， it has no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to import `Axes3D` and instantiate it to create a 3D plot. In fact, looking at the [official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/index.html), the suggested way is to call the `add_subplot(projection="3d")` method from a figure. Here is how:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

figure = plt.figure()
ax = figure.add_subplot(projection="3d")
X = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
Y = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = (np.sin(X)*np.sin(Y))/(X*Y)  # f(x,y)=(sin(x)*sin(y))/(x*y)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='rainbow')
plt.show()
```